# How to return from JavaScript object with type java.util.Date?

Tags: java, javascript, date, gwt, jsni

I'm calling in JS some `javaMethod(java.util.Date date)`.

I can't change code on java-side. How can I create java.util.Date object from JS-side (at least empty date)?

Comment: Java and Javascript are two completely different things.

Comment: Of course I know that it's a different things. I'm using native functions (JSNI) in my java-GWT code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in a not very good way, but still..

So now I'm just added to that method with JS just one more `Date` arg.
Now it looks like

```
native void doSomething(Object object, Date date) /*-{
  .....
  .....::setDate(Ljava/util/Date;)(date);
  .....
}-*/;
```

and calling it like  `doSomething(var1, new Date());`

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use java date in javascript use javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var date = new Date();
```

Just get the long value from javascript date and pass to java.

in javascript get time in milliseconds as

```
var timeinmillis = new Date().getTime();
```

and pass this to java.

in java , look at the constructor

[`public Date(long date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29)

Comment: I know all that stuff, thanks, but java method accepts only `Date` object. I'll need one more "layer" to create Date object with `long`. But  I don't have it.